# davfs: syntax error in secrets file

Tags: linux, davfs2

I have here a linux system which should mount a (remote) davfs file system. All is fine and if I mount the file system manually from command line it works:

```
/> mount /share/davDrives/private 
Gib bitte den Benutzernamen für den Server https://data011.fritz.box/webdav/Shared/Public an; wenn du keinen angeben willst, drücke Return.
  Benutzername: username
Gib bitte das Passwort von username für den Server https://data011.fritz.box/webdav/Shared/Public
an; wenn du keines angeben willst, drücke Return.
  Passwort:
```

(it's a german installation) After that the file system is mounted successfully.

But I want to mount the file system automatically. To do that I must put username and password into a ~/.davfs2/secrets file:

```
/share/davDrives/private  username  myPasswordIsTopSecret
```

But if I try to mount the davfs the I get:

```
/> mount /share/davDrives/private 
/sbin/mount.davfs:/home/stewert.c-on/.davfs2/secrets:1: Syntaxfehler in der Zeile
```

("Syntaxfehler in der Zeile" == "Syntax error in line")

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong?!? Difficult to find, but simple:

In my case there was in the secrets file a white space (" ") behind the password ... ;-) That's all!